# SecurityError: The operation is insecure when i try to access the image from the other server

Tags: javascript

When I try to get an image from the other server, I'm getting an error SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

And if I use the image from the same server where my code is then it works why?

Comment: Because it's insecure to use other site resources.

Comment: You should only refer to resources that are on the same server / hosted on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

The resource from another location might be changed, this is causing SecurityError.

You should only include resources from the same domain and subdomain, with the same protocol.